# Style last child of div with certain class

Tags: css

I have two DIV with the class "wrapper".
I want to style them in general, and give special style to the last one:

```
<div class="cont">   

<span class="help">
<div class="wrapper">aaaa</div>
</span>


<span class="help">
<div class="wrapper">bbbbb</div>
</span>

</div>
```

(In my real example I have multiple divs inside the span, so I need to target this certain class)

I tried various CSS rules:

```
div.wrapper {  background:green;   }
div.wrapper:last-child{ background:red; }

div > span > div.wrapper {  background:green;   }
div > span > div.wrapper:last-child{ background:red; }

div .wrapper {  background:green;   }
div .wrapper:last-child{ background:red; }
```

Nothing, worked, not even:

```
div div {  background:green;   }
div div:last-of-type { background:red; }
```

It always makes everything in Red, as if every DIV is the last child.

Comment: "It always makes everything in Red, as if every DIV is the last child." That's because every child div *is* the last child... of its parent span. (Notwithstanding the fact that a div in a span is invalid HTML to begin with.)

Comment: considering I must have this span in the code, how do I ignore the span's being a parent?

Comment: You don't, you actually are interested in the div that's in the last span.

Comment: use last-child with span then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`:last-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child) is relative to the parent, so here:

```
<div class="cont">   
    <span class="help">
        <div class="wrapper">aaaa</div>
    </span>

    <span class="help">
        <div class="wrapper">bbbbb</div>
    </span>
</div>
```

The `.wrapper` with text `aaaa` is the `:last-child` of the first `<span>` with class `.help`, and the second `.wrapper` with text `bbbbb` is also the `:last-child` of the the second `<span>` with class `.help`.

You need to apply the `:last-child` selector to `.help` instead, which will select the last `.help`, and then use a [descendant](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors) or [child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) selector to target the `.wrapper` inside it:

```
.help:last-child > .wrapper
```

If you can also have multiple `.wrapper` inside a single `.help` and you only want to select the last one, then it would be:

```
.help:last-child > .wrapper:last-child
```

Here's an example:

```css
body {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.cont {
  border: 3px solid #000;
  margin: 0 0 3px;
}

.help + .help {
  margin: 3px 0 0;
}

.wrapper {
  background: #F0F;
  padding: 1px 6px;
}

.help:last-child > .wrapper:last-child {
  background: #FF0;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont"> 
  <div class="help">
      <div class="wrapper">AAA</div>
  </div>

  <div class="help">
      <div class="wrapper">BBB</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="cont"> 
  <div class="help">
      <div class="wrapper">CCC</div>
  </div>

  <div class="help">
      <div class="wrapper">DDD</div>
  </div>

  <div class="help">
      <div class="wrapper">EEE 1</div>
      <div class="wrapper">EEE 2</div>
      <div class="wrapper">EEE 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you have pointed out in the comments, if the last element inside a `.cont` is not a `.help`, but the previous one is, this one (the previous one) will not be selected.

The best option would be to use [`:nth-last-child( <nth> [ of <selector># ]? )`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-last-child):

```
.help:nth-last-child(1 of .help) > .wrapper:last-child
```

But support for [Selectors Level 4](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#the-nth-child-pseudo) is still quite low...

An alternative with good support would be to use [`:last-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type), but it has a limitation: Now, the element that you use for `.help` has to be different to the other ones used as children (direct descendant) of `.cont`:

```css
body {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.cont {
  border: 3px solid #000;
  margin: 0 0 3px;
}

.help + .help {
  margin: 3px 0 0;
}

.foo {
  display: block;
  background: #0FF;
  margin: 3px 0 0;
  padding: 1px 6px;
}

.wrapper {
  background: #F0F;
  padding: 1px 6px;
}

.help:last-of-type > .wrapper:last-child {
  background: #FF0;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont"> 
  <div class="help">
      <div class="wrapper">CCC</div>
  </div>

  <div class="help">
      <div class="wrapper">DDD</div>
  </div>

  <div class="help">
      <div class="wrapper">EEE 1</div>
      <div class="wrapper">EEE 2</div>
      <div class="wrapper">EEE 3</div>
  </div>
  
  <!-- Note I'm using a <span> here -->
  <span class="foo">Hi there.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've tried the code, and my issue is that if I add a `<div>xxxx</div>` , right before the `cont` DIV is closing, the whole thing wouldn't work...

Comment: @rockyraw Please, check the update. That might be closer to what you want.